# Use one argument for template parameter deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

Let’s say I have a template function, `assign()`. It takes a pointer and a value and assigns the value to the pointer’s target:

```
template <typename T> void assign(T *a, T b) { *a = b; }

int main() {
    double i;
    assign(&i, 2);
}
```

In this case I always want `T` to be deduced from the first argument, but it looks like I didn’t do a good job of expressing this. `2`’s type is `int`, so:

```
deduce.cpp:5:5: error: no matching function for call to 'assign'
    assign(&i, 2);
    ^~~~~~
deduce.cpp:1:28: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('double' vs. 'int')
template  void assign(T *a, T b) { *a = b; }
```

---

Is there a way I can declare `assign()` so that the second argument doesn’t participate in template parameter deduction?

Comment: So, one problem with the above is inefficiency.  Suppose `T` is `std::vector`.  The argument `b` is taken by-value, then copied (not moved) into `a`.  A small improvement might be changing the implementation of `assign` to `*a = std::move(b)`, which for primitive types costs nothing, and for complex types could save a lot.  A large improvement would be to perfect forward `b`.

Comment: @Yakk Totally agreed — I just wrote it as an example of a function that takes a pointer to and value of the same type. In actuality it only takes primitives and is more useful than this guy :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++20 has `std::type_identity` which can be used to establish a non-deduced context:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void assign(T *a, std::type_identity_t<T> b) {
    *a = b;
}

int main() {
    double i;
    assign(&i, 2);
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ey44MzbnHyfLFz14)

Answer (score 13):

Using two type parameters is probably the best option, but if you really want to perform deduction only from the first argument, simply make the second non-deducible:

```
template<typename T>
void assign( T* a, typename std::identity<T>::type b );
```

- Demo: http://ideone.com/ZW6Mpu

---

An earlier version of this answer suggested using the template alias feature introduced in C++11.  But template aliases are still a deducible context.  The primary reason that `std::identity` and `std::remove_reference` prevents deduction is that template classes can be specialized, so even if you have a typedef of a template type parameter, it's possible that another specialization has a typedef of the same type.  Because of the possible ambiguity, deduction doesn't take place.  But template aliases preclude specialization, and so deduction still occurs.

Comment: +1. Given the edit to the question (which I missed), this seems to be the right answer.

Comment: This is a really cool answer but it doesn’t work for me. I get the same “conflicting types” error from my compiler: ideone.com/GIJbj1

Comment: Looks like `std::remove_reference` is equivalent (if a little less readable), too.

Comment: @Sidnicious: My bad, looks like template aliases are still deducible :(

Comment: There is no `std::identity`, is there?

Comment: @aschepler: [g++ thinks so](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00497.html).  But see the ideone link for a trivial reimplementation not using any standard headers.

Comment: @aschepler you appear to be right, it was suggested but then removed from C++11: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/vrrtKvA7cqo

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the compiler is deducing conflicting information from the first and the second argument. From the first argument, it deduces `T` to be `double` (`i` is a `double)`; from the second one, it deduces `T` to be `int` (the type of `2` is `int`).

You have two main possibilities here:

- Always be explicit about the type of your arguments:

  ```
  assign(&i, 2.0);
  //         ^^^^
  ```
- Or let your function template accept *two* template parameters:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename U> 
  void assign(T *a, U b) { *a = b; }
  ```

  In this case, you may want to SFINAE-constraint the template so that it does not partecipate to overload resolution in case `U` is not convertible to `T`:

  ```
  #include <type_traits>

  template <typename T, typename U,
      typename std::enable_if<
          std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  void assign(T *a, U b) { *a = b; }
  ```

  If you do not need to exclude your function from the overload set when `U` is not convertible to `T`, you may want to have a static assertion inside `assign()` to produce a nicer compilation error:

  ```
  #include <type_traits>

  template<typename T, typename U>
  void assign(T *a, U b)
  {
      static_assert(std::is_convertible<T, U>::value,
          "Error: Source type not convertible to destination type.");

      *a = b;
  }
  ```

Comment: Or `static_assert` within the function, since you don't have another overload that is viable in the non-convertible case.

Comment: @Praetorian: Or that, yes. I wasn't thinking of it because the function is small and the error message would be understandable anyway, but you're right, it's an option

Comment: Sorry about the late edit — this is a pretty legit answer. Upvoted, at least.

Answer (score 3):

It's just that the value `2` is deduced to the type `int`, which doesn't match the template parameter deduced by `&i`. You need to use the value as a double:

```
assign(&i, 2.0);
```

Comment: I know. That works but it’s brittle and ugly — if `i` is an `unsigned long` then my second argument has to be `2ul`, if it’s a float it has to be `(float)2`, etc. In the real code, it takes a few arguments and gets nasty fast.

Comment: @Sidnicious Then I guess you might want to go with Andy's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use *two* independent parameter types, one for the source and one for the destination?

```
template <typename D, typename S> void assign(D *a, S b) { *a = b; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double i;
    assign(&i, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

If the assignment is not possible, the template instantiation won't compile.

Comment: odd using `D` for the source and `S` for the destination

Comment: @Ben: Indeed :) Just swapped them.

Comment: If you are going to do this, why not forward `S` perfectly?

Answer (score 1):

My attempt would look something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_convertible< U&&, T >::value >::type // not quite perfect
assign( T* dest, U&& src ) {
  *dest = std::forward<U>(src);
}
```

the second argument is anything you can convert to a `T`, but we take it by universal reference and conditionally move it into `*dest`.  I test for convertability in the signature rather than have the body fail to compile, because failure-to-find-an-overload seems more polite than failing to compile-the-body.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/9Atdr7).

Compared to the simpler:

```
template<typename T>
void assign( T* dest, typename std::identity<T>::type src ) {
  *dest = std::move(src);
}
```

the above saves 1 `move`.  If you have an expensive to move class, or a class that is copy-only and expensive to copy, this could save a significant amount.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `decltype` to typecast the second argument to be the type of first.

```
template <typename T> void assign(T *a, T b) { *a = b; }

int main() {
    double i;
    assign(&i, (decltype(i))2);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but you have to remember to do that every time you call it. It gets ugly fast — I posted this question because was I was trying to improve a function took several numbers as arguments. Casts everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `std::identity` is not there anymore ([Is there a reason why there is not std::identity in the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35907848/320369))

But you can specify the parameter type in the parameter type list, when calling the function:

```
template <typename T> void assign(T *a, T b) { *a = b; }

int main() {
  double i;
  assign<double>(&i, 2);
}
```

In this way the compiler will convert the integer input argument to double to match the function template, without argument deduction.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/wDpGM4)