# Is there a reason why there is not std::identity in the standard library?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, identity, negate

When dealing with generic code in C++, I would find a `std::identity` functor (like `std::negate`) very useful. Is there a particular reason why this is not present in the standard library?

Comment: It was present in pre-C++11 drafts. IIRC, it was used to prevent template argument deduction in [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). Somewhere along the way, someone realized `remove_reference` was needed for `forward`, which also took care of the non-deducible context part, and maybe `identity` was no longer used by anything else, so it got dropped.

Comment: Interestingly, some C++ implementations seem to use a `std::_Identity` template internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soon after std::identity was introduced, issues began to appear, starting with conflicts to pre-cpp98 definitions of std::identity appearing as extensions: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/vrrtKvA7cqo
This site might give a little more history for it.

Comment: Identity can be used to prevent template argument deduction. Boost::clamp uses this trick. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767240/what-is-stdidentity-and-how-it-is-used.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20, there is an [`std::identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity) functor type with an `operator()` template member function. This function call operator returns its argument.

---

For example, if you have such a function template:

```
template<typename T, typename Operation>
void print_collection(const T& coll, Operation op) {
    std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type> out(std::cout, " ");
    std::transform(std::begin(coll), std::end(coll), out, op);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

and wanted to print the elements of `vec`:

```
std::vector vec = {1, 2, 3};
```

you would do something like:

```
print_collection(vec, [](auto val) { return val; });
```

With `std::identity`, you could do:

```
print_collection(vec, std::identity());
```

The line above seems to specify this intention more clearly.